# Webpack dev server live reload with proxy

Tags: proxy, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I'm running a `PHP` app at `localhost:8000`.
I want to use `webpack-dev-server` to hot reload `css`, `react` and `js` components.
Had set a proxy to `http://localhost:8000` but `webpack-dev-server` **isn't reloading** the browser.

Here's the `webpack.config.js`:

```
var path = require( 'path' );
var autoprefixer = require( 'autoprefixer' );

module.exports = {
    entry: [
        './src/app.js'
    ],
    output: {
        path: path.join( __dirname, 'dist' ),
        publicPath: 'http://localhost:8000',
        filename: 'app.js'
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loaders: [ 'react-hot', 'babel-loader' ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                loaders: [ 'style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader' ]
            }
        ]
    },
    postcss: [
        autoprefixer(
            {
                browsers: [
                    'last 2 versions'
                ]
            }
        )
    ],
    devServer: {
        port: 3000,
        proxy: {
            '**': {
                target: 'http://localhost:8000',
                secure: false,
                changeOrigin: true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm accessing the `webpack-dev-server` at `http://localhost:3000/webpack-dev-server/`.

Changing my `react` component does cause `webpack-dev-server` to recompile, but the browser doesn't update.

Running `webpack` does compile the `dist/app.js` file, as calling it manually and reloading the browser works.

Answer (score -1):

So my `publicPath` was wrong.
Here's the fix:

```
output: {
    path: path.join( __dirname, 'dist' ),
    publicPath: 'http://localhost:3000/dist/',
    filename: 'app.js'
},
```

**update:** But it seems to be reloading the browser ¯_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Did you every manage to solve this? I am also trying out proxy and after the change the whole browser refreshes instead of injecting the changes without refresh. I am using webpack-dev-server and react-hot-reload on client side and node server on server side.

Comment: I think I did. But its been a while. Can't remember what I did :)

Comment: I know the felling : ) If you ever remember or have some code example please post it. There doesn't seem to be solution to this on whole internet :)

Comment: I don't have access to it anymore cause I left. Should had blogged about it. Maybe you can blog about it when you do find out :)